# What resources are available to read and share pyglet code?

Tags: 3d, opengl, python, pyglet

I am a Python programmer (I know the ins and outs decently well), and I have dabbled with Pygame. I want to make 3D applications and games, and so naturally I've been looking at OpenGL.

pyglet uses OpenGL, and the [programming website and documentation](http://www.pyglet.org/documentation.html) is up there with the best I've seen as far as libraries and APIs go.

Is there a place on the net where other pyglet programmers go to share projects and source code, [like there is for Pygame](http://pygame.org)?

I would love to see how other people are combining game logic and OpenGL graphical code to create a simple game (it really helps the learning process).

Comment: Does it really need to be pyglet then, if you're just looking for game logic combined with graphical code? And for that matter, python at all?

Answer (score 4):

[pyglet has a mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/pyglet-users) but no active web presence (or development at all) right now. In general people working on pyglet code are encouraged to submit to pygame.org, and many also [participate in PyWeek](http://pyweek.org/); there are many completed pyglet games there, although because of the time pressure the code is usually not great, even when the programmers are skilled.

Comment: Thanks for editing my original question :] - also, I think something needs to be said about the quality of games that show up during PyWeek (I had NO idea Pyglet programmers are among these applicants..same with Pygame.org).  I will download source of these games and take a look as an additional resource of learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

People post things made using Pyglet and PyOpenGL to pygame.org. The games list is open to anything in Python, not just the Pygame library.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a lengthy post about producing retro vector graphics using OpenGL from pyglet:

https://www.tartley.com/posts/flying-high-opengl-from-python-part-2/

[image]